# Voice over wifi between android phones in C#

Tags: c#, android, wifi, monodevelop, voice

I want to develop an application for voice calls between two android devices on my home network (WiFi). I'm new to programming so don't really know where to begin, I have researched around but cannot find anything that fits what I need to do.

The application has to be written in C# as I have a basic understanding of that language and it's the language I want to expand my knowledge in. I'm using MonoDevelop which allows the creation of android apps through C#.

The call will be peer to peer so very basic and no security or encryption will be necessary in these early stages of development.

All help will really be appreciated!

Comment: Insisting on an atypical language for a platform will greatly reduce the chance of finding ready to use examples you can draw on.

Comment: I understand that thanks Chris, unfortunately i don't have the experience to look at say; java code and know how to re-write it in c# for android.

Comment: If you are capable in C#, you should not have problems doing rudimentary development *in* java when you have examples to start with.  The challenges are overwhelmingly architectural, and secondarily driven by platform constraints, not with language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with this link at code project:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138484/Simple-SIP-VOIP-based-phone-in-C

You will have to adapt it to android, but again is a probably a good starting point to understand how to do voice over IP.

The big things that may differ on android are:

1. User interface
2. method to get microphone input
3. method to play audio output
4. access to the IP stack

but the basic (encoding, decoding, etc...) should be there.

Comment: Thanks David, this app looks great. Still struggling to get it changed over to work with android.. where would you advise starting?